# Mixing code-generated view controllers and storyboards

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uikit, interface-builder, storyboard, hierarchy

I've got a huge storyboard with lots of views defined. Now I created an additional view (and it's view controller) completely in code. How do I use that new, code-generated view in a storyboard? To make this a little bit more clear: I have three view controllers: A, B and C. A and C are defined via storyboards and work just fine. B is the one I generated in code. How do I wire this up?

I found a quite a few answers—but all of them did only work the other way around.

Thanks!
–f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only wire those code-generated view controllers with code too.

Firstly, create the subclass of the viewController, e.g. A and C, that you have in storyboard so that you can modify those view controllers from storyboard with code.

Then, use the navigationController `pushViewController:animated:` method to push the code-generated view controller, e.g. B or the view controller methods, e.g. A or C, `presentViewController:animated:completion:` to present the view controller modally.

If you want to push view controllers from storyboard within code-generated view controllers, you can use the storyboard method `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`. Just remember to set the Storyboard ID of the view controllers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sure, that's not problem. Maybe I was not clear enough. What's the proper way, after doing what you've described, to get back to the next view controller C, which has been layed out in that storyboard? I do have custom view controllers for all of those views, but only the controller B does define it's views in code. So how do I show illustrate that scenario in my storyboard?

Comment: Yup, you can use storyboard method of instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: within B.